# Passing variable in function

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, variables

This is for a sorting script. I want to order my posts by votes. I'm using an if-statement in a function to check what order by was selected and display posts according to that.

The following function inserts data in my query.

```
function vote_orderby( $orderby )
{
  global $vote_sort;

  if( $vote_sort == "most_voted") {
     // order by most votes
     return "votes DESC"; //inserts into query
  }

  // return default order by if no votes
  return $orderby;
}
```

HTML

```
$vote_sort = "most_voted"; //should be picked up by function

..function
..loop
```

I want to generate,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY votes DESC";
```

But posts are ordered by date. It works however without the if-statement, this ensures that I have no MYSQL errors.

How is it possible to pass the `$vote_sort` value into the function?

*Note: I'm aware of the SQL injection risk, I will filter everything soon.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your comment and expand on Michael's solution above, here is what you might want to do...

```
 function vote_orderby($orderby) {  
    switch($orderby) {
       // Sort by most votes
       case 'most_voted': $sort = 'votes DESC'; break;
       // Sort by least votes
       case 'least_voted': $sort = 'votes ASC'; break;
       // Default to most votes if does not match any other option
       default: $sort = 'votes DESC'; break;
    }
    return $sort; // Return query statement
 }
```

Then your query statement would be such as...

```
$sortby = $_GET['sort']; // However you want to get the way to sort
// If $sortby is empty, it will default to most_voted via function
$order = vote_orderby($sortby);
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY ".$order;
```

This is more of a permanent way of coding the system and prevent people to inject your MYSQL query and minor mistakes will not result in the future.

I have coded many similar systems in the past and this is one of the best ways to go.

Comment: thanks for the code it looks good! However for some reason it always uses the default switch. I don't think it's picking up the `$sortby` variable. I even tried `$sortby = "least_voted"` and it's still using the default. Something seems off.

Comment: Did you try to echo out the results from the variable $order to see what the function is actually returning? This way you can find out if the switch is right with the function and the Database might be off. Try to do that and let me know the results :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
 function vote_orderby( $orderby='most_voted' ) {  
   if( $orderby == "most_voted") {    
      // order by most votes  
      return "votes DESC"; //inserts into query  
   }  

  // return default order by if no votes  
 return $orderby;  
 }
```

In your query you want something simular to this

```
// this will give you the default;
$orderby = vote_orderby();
$query = 'SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY ' . $orderby;
```

Or

```
// this will give you the name;
$orderby = vote_orderby('NAME DESC');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY ' . $orderby;
```

But you might just want to set a variable to the sort method and pass that into your query. Doing this in a function is a bit of a overkill or you could just add the whole query inthere and return the right one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Using your code, the `$order_by` variable returns `votes DESC`. I need `most_voted` and this value can change to `least_voted` as well. I should have also mentioned that the function is part of a WordPress filter for querying posts. The $orderby is for modifying the MYSQL only. I need a seprate variable to deal with the sorting.